# Websphre MQ identifying connected clients

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using websphere mq and JMS API to connect to MQ.I am using message selector for connecting and grouping the messages.

Actually my problem is that there are some cases where JMS client can connect with same Message Selector(CO-relation ID), so whenever any client tries to connect to MQ then i want a way to check whether that Is there any other client with same message selector is already connected or not, and If present then I need to stop him from connecting an I will abort his connection.

Is there any way to intercept the Websphere MQ connections before connecting?

Regards,
Pravin

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly at connect time, as in JMS a message selector is undefined at the time you create the connection: i.e. you first do

> Connection c = myConnectionFactory.createConnection();

and then later on do

> MessageConsumer con = mySession.createConsumer(myDestination, mySelector);

so when you connect the queue manager has no way of knowing what selector you will subsequently use (or even if you will specify one at all)

One possibility might be to use durable subscriptions, see

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/TopicSession.html#createDurableSubscriber

(or the cross-domain JMS 1.1 equivalent). These are uniquely identified by a combination of clientId, subscriber name, and Topic, and the JMS specification requires that

> If another connection with the same clientID is already running ... the JMS provider should detect the duplicate ID and throw an InvalidClientIDException.

the client ID is specified on the ConnectionFactory, so is closer to what you want, although switching to durable Pub/Sub is not necessarily a simple option. Before even considering that, you should probably look at whether or not there is an application level fix for the "cases where JMS client can connect with same Message Selector"

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I have tried to use Same client Id but MQ is allowing to connect , so I am not getting any exception also.

Comment: As far as I remember client ID will only be checked with durable pub/sub, it won't be enforced in point-to-point or non-durable pub/sub modes